# Create a JFrame using JNI

Tags: java, c++, macos, swing, java-native-interface

I have java Library that I need to call from C++, using JNI I was able to call the methods on the java library successfully except for one.

The problematic method creates a JFrame and causes the jvm to get stuck on a deadlock when running on MacOS, after some research I found that any interaction with JNI that involves AWT/swing must not be done from the main thread.

So I modified the code to make all the calls to the JVM on a secondary thread, but I still have issues with the same method. I got the JFrame to display, but after that the C++ code gets blocked on the CFRunLoopRunInMode function call until I close the JFrame, and then the process terminates abruptly.

Currently my code looks like this (This is a simplified version, but essentially the same. Also error handling was omitted from the C++ code for simplicity):

Java Code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyClass extends JFrame
{
    private Thread frameThread;

    public void createFrame()
    {
        System.out.println("Creating Frame Thread");
        frameThread = new Thread(() -> {
            setTitle("JFrameCenter Position");
            add(new JLabel("JFrame set to center of the screen", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setSize(400, 300);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null); // this method display the JFrame to center position of a screen
            setVisible(true);
        });

        System.out.println("Starting Frame Thread");
        frameThread.start();
    }
}
```

C++ Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

#define JLI_DYLIB "/lib/jli/libjli.dylib"
#define JNI_CREATEVM_FUNC "JNI_CreateJavaVM"
typedef jint (JNICALL CreateJavaVM_t)(JavaVM **pvm, void **env, void *args);

void* DyLibHandler;
JavaVM *jvm;

CFRunLoopRef currentLoopRef;
CFRunLoopSourceRef sourceRef;

void *GetStartJvmFunc(std::string javaHome) {
    std::string jliPath = javaHome.append(JLI_DYLIB);
    DyLibHandler = dlopen(jliPath.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!DyLibHandler)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    void * jvmFunc = dlsym(DyLibHandler, JNI_CREATEVM_FUNC);
    if  (!jvmFunc)
    {
        dlclose(DyLibHandler);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    return jvmFunc;
}

void StartJvm(const char * javaHome, const char * classPath) {
    std::string jarsPath = "-Djava.class.path=";
    std::string home = "-Djava.home=";
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[3];   // JVM invocation options
    options[0].optionString = (char*)jarsPath.append(classPath).c_str();
    options[0].extraInfo = NULL;
    options[1].optionString = (char*)home.append(javaHome).c_str();
    options[1].extraInfo = NULL;
    options[2].optionString = "-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=10";
    options[2].extraInfo = NULL;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = 3;
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    
    JNIEnv *jniEnvironment;
    CreateJavaVM_t* createVMFunc = (CreateJavaVM_t*)GetStartJvmFunc(std::string(javaHome));
    jint rc = createVMFunc(&jvm, (void**)&jniEnvironment, &vm_args);  // YES !!
    delete[] options;    // we then no longer need the initialisation options.
    if (rc != JNI_OK) {
        createVMFunc = NULL;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void CreateJFrame(JNIEnv *jniEnvironment)
{
    jclass localHandler = jniEnvironment->FindClass("MyClass");
    if (!localHandler)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not Find LocalClass" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    jclass classHandle = (jclass) jniEnvironment->NewGlobalRef(localHandler);
    jniEnvironment->DeleteLocalRef(localHandler);
    
    jmethodID constructorHandler = jniEnvironment->GetMethodID(classHandle, "<init>", "()V");
    if (!constructorHandler)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not find Constructor" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    jmethodID createMethodHandler = jniEnvironment->GetMethodID(classHandle, "createFrame", "()V");
    if (!createMethodHandler)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not Find CreateFrame Method" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    jobject localRef = jniEnvironment->NewObject(classHandle, constructorHandler);
    if(!localRef)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not instantiate MyClass" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    jobject classInstance = jniEnvironment->NewGlobalRef(localRef);
    jniEnvironment->DeleteLocalRef(localRef);
    if (classInstance == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create global ref to MyClass instance" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    jniEnvironment->CallVoidMethod(classInstance, createMethodHandler);
}

void SourceCallback (  void *info  ) {
    
    std::cout << "From Source Callback! Got Event" << std::endl;
}

void * ThreadProc(void * arg)
{
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    jint result =jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&env, NULL);
    if( result != JNI_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Error! Could not attach JNIEnv to thread (" << result << ")"<< std::endl;
        goto clean;
    }
    
    CreateJFrame(env);
    
    std::cout << "Deataching Thread" << std::endl;
    result = jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
    if(result != JNI_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Error! could not deatached current thread (" << result << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Done Deataching Thread" << std::endl;
    }
    
clean:
    std::cout << "Done Creating Frame" << std::endl;
    CFRunLoopSourceSignal(sourceRef);
    CFRunLoopWakeUp(currentLoopRef);
    std::cout << "Done signalling RunLoop" << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    currentLoopRef = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
    CFRunLoopSourceContext sourceContext;
    sourceContext.version = 0;
    sourceContext.info = NULL;
    sourceContext.retain = NULL;
    sourceContext.release = NULL;
    sourceContext.copyDescription = NULL;
    sourceContext.equal = NULL;
    sourceContext.hash = NULL;
    sourceContext.schedule = NULL;
    sourceContext.cancel = NULL;
    sourceContext.perform = &SourceCallback;
    sourceRef = CFRunLoopSourceCreate(NULL, 0, &sourceContext);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(currentLoopRef, sourceRef, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    
    StartJvm(/*JavaHome*/, /*ClassPaht*/);
    
    pthread_t vmThread;
    pthread_create(&vmThread, NULL, ThreadProc, NULL);
    CFRunLoopRunResult result = CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 10, TRUE);
    std::cout << "Done with Loop Run" << std::endl;
}
```

With the code above I would expect the frame to display and immediately close, and see the prints from the `SourceCallback` function and the print after the call to `CFRunLoopRunInMode` on the console. But what happens is that the frame does not close and neither of the two prints happened, I have to manually close the Frame and then the program terminates without printing anything.

Also I tried using a while loop instead of the `CFRunLoopRunInMode` but the same deadlock on the VM happened. Even if I don't signal the CFRunLoopSource the program does not terminates(the CFRunLoop does not time out) until I close the JFrame manually and the last print does not happend.

I have been stuck in the problem for a while and I am clueless on what is happening.
Why the program "waits" until the Frame is closed to abruptly terminate?
Why the CFRunLoop ignores the events and the time out timer?

EDIT:
I update the C++ code to remove the global `JNIEnv *`, by creating the pointer to `JavaVm` on the main thread and calling `AttachToCurrentThread` from the secondary thread to obtain a valid `JNIEnv`. Sadly the program behaves the same as before, the JFrame gets display and the main thread gets stuck until I close the JFrame.

Also I notice that I had forgot to add the new source to the CFRunLoop, that is why the source callback wasn't getting called after signalling the the CFRunLoop from the secondary thread. Now I see the print from the source callback but the main thread is still stuck on the CFRunLoop.

Comment: I don't understand.  You mention you are programming in C, but used the C++ tag.  The C and C++ are different languages.  For example, C++ allows function overloading but C doesn't.  C++ has `std::string` and `std::vector` types, C doesn't.  C++ has inheritance, C doesn't.  Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: You shiould not save `JNIEnv* statically, as it isn't valid across JNI invocations. See the JNI Specification. You should have it as a local variable and pass it around as needed.

Comment: I see a bunch of threads and 0 synchronization. That's a recipe for undefined behavior.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sorry about the confusion, to clarify I am working in C++, I mess up when writing the question. I have updated it and  hopefully is not confusing anymore.

Comment: @rustyx with the code as is right now (after the update), please correct me If I am wrong here, but I don't think I need to synchronize anything in the C++ side, should I add the synchronization on the Java side to wait for the thread to finish?